# Spanish for "some" in this context

Tags: gramática

How would one translate the following sentence into Spanish?

> **I made some hot chocolate for the kids.**

My attempt is:

> **Preparé chocolate caliente para los niños.**

But I am unable to figure out something for the "some" there. I can't use **poco** because that would mean "a little". Can't even use **unos** because...shouldn't **unos** be used with countable nouns?

Comment: You don't really need anything for that *some* in Spanish. Your translation looks perfectly good.

Comment: Careful with the tense. It think your translation of "preparé" con "he preparado" as others suggested is VERY understandable in Spanish, but if you want to really emphasize the moment of the preparation is exactly the same as in Present Perfect and Simple Past. "Preparé" when you already finish at some point in the past and "He preparado" it's like you have been doing chocolate and you finished at the moment .. ready to serve!

Comment: As I discused with my Colombian friends, generally for them they prefer to use the Simple Past for everything that started in the past, but for Peruvians it's complicated, sometimes Simple Past and Present Perfect according to the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about,

> He preparado **algo de** chocolate caliente para los niños.

Consider the use like in

> Queda **algo de** queso, por si te quieres preparar un bocadillo <sub>There is still **some** cheese left, in case you want to prepare yourself a sandwich</sub>

Doesn't necessarily need to mean "a little", but could have that inflection, so is really similar to "a little" but without conveying scarcity that much.

> Todavía queda algo de nieve en las calles <sub>There is still some snow in the streets</sub>

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, you can use *algo de chocolate* which would be the most natural sounding, but if you really want to use *poco*, you can using the same structure.  Note the difference in usages of poco as adjective or as noun<sup>1</sup>:

- Preparé poco chocolate caliente
  <sup>(I made a rather meager and insufficient amount of hot chocolate)</sup>
- Preparé un poco de chocolate caliente
  <sup>(I made some hot chocolate to whet everyone's appetite)</sup>

---

<sup>1. If I recall correctly from talking with a friend, in Mexico they're known for using *poco* a bit differently than the rest of the Spanish-speaking world, but I can't remember the exact differences.</sup>

Comment: Brillante explicación de cómo "poco" puede usarse tanto para "no suficiente cantidad" como para "suficiente".

Comment: As a native Spanish speaker, "un poco" is actually the more natural sounding alternative.

Answer (score 3):

The literally translation will be:

> Preparé **algo de(some)** chocolate caliente para los niños.

You can read this link: http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/some, `algo` means `some` when referring to a quantity of a thing.

You can also use `un`:

> Preparé **un** chocolate caliente para los niños.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use "some" in English or Spanish. In the English original, "some" is a bonus word. The sentence is semantically identical when it is omitted:

> I made hot chocolate for the kids.

is the same as

> I made **some** hot chocolate for the kids.

No one would think that you made none or all of the hot chocolate if you omit the "some".

In Spanish, you can omit "some":

*Preparé chocolate para los niños*.

is the equivalent of

*I made some hot chocolate for the kids*.

You don't really need *caliente* since the candy form of chocolate would be a *dulce* of one kind or another.

Caution: when you use *algo* in Spanish, it can have another meaning that does not appear to be intended here.

In the sentence *Había algo de nieve en la calle.*, the term *algo* suggests a final remnant of small quantity, a scant presence or hint. That's definitely not what I understood you meant by "I made some hot chocolate for the kids."

*Preparé algo de comida y fui a dormir* would translate as "I made myself something to eat and went to sleep." The *algo* suggests that whatever you made, it wasn't substantial and that you were in a hurry to get to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

> Hice chocolate para los niños.

In Spanish, chocolate is not only the candy, but the hot beverage (hot is implied in this sense). You normally would not make the candy, you would buy it. But if you made the beverage, it is supposed to be a hot infusion of chocolate in water.

In this case, `preparar` means more steps than just `hacer`. It is the same as in English you said `I prepared some chocolate for the kids` instead of `I made...`

Relating to the `algo de`, You would say `hice chocolate`, an indeterminate, unmeasurable quantity of chocolate. If it is good English to say `I made some chocolate`, it would be one of those nuances that differentiate both languages. That is maybe why in English I would say `I made chocolate`, being a native Spanish speaker.

Answer (score 1):

your translation is perfect

I made some hot chocolate for the kids.

hice un poco de chocolate caliente para los niños.